# ssh and GIT: couldn't resolve hostname

Tags: windows, git, ssh, gitolite

Using Win7, Gitolite, and TortoiseGIT

today I updated my GIT to version 2.6.1, therefore I had to deinstall the old version.
Long time ago I created a ssh-config file to have easier access to my repositories and all was working fine since today.

After the update I tried to clone an existing repository and got following error:

```
ssh: couldn't resolve hostname gitbox: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Seems to me like GIT doesn't know where the ssh-config file is located.

Following helped but I'm not very happy with that solution:

1. Starting GIT GUI
2. Trying to clone a repository -> Same error as before
3. figured out that GIT created a new folder at /c/Users/newUser/
4. Inside the folder I found .gitconfig
5. Create .ssh folder here
6. Copy rsa key and config file here
7. All working as before

Can someone explain what happened here? Or how can I tell GIT/ssh where my config file was initially located?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone explain what happened here?

You need to make sure that HOME is properly set to `%USERPROFILE%`: by default, git will look for the global config and for `.ssh` settings in `%HOME%`.

By default, calling `c:\path\to\PortableGit-2.6.1-64-bit\git-cmd.exe` would initiate a CMD session with HOME correctly set.
`c:\path\to\PortableGit-2.6.1-64-bit\git-bash.exe` would do the same for `$HOME`, in a bash session.